# Using and updating a NSMutableString in AppDelegate for two viewcontrollers

Tags: xcode, variables, viewcontroller, appdelegate

I have a NSMutableString defined in my AppDelegate.h file.

```
//AppDelegate.h
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>{
  @public
    NSMutableString *nidForDetailDisplay;
}
```

Then I set this string in my ViewController.m file. I am storing a string (nidForDetailDisplay) to pass from a tableview to detailview.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

  rowNumber = indexPath.row;

  AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
      // this is where I set the string to a string of text
    appDelegate->theNidForDetailDisplay = [arrayOfNids objectAtIndex:rowNumber];

  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  UIViewController *detailViewController;

  DetailViewController *detail = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detail"];

  [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];

 }
```

In ViewController, when I log theNidForDetailDisplay, I get the correct string.

Next, I try to access this updated NSMutableString (nidForDetailDisplay) in the subsequent DetailViewController

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

[super viewWillAppear:animated];

 NSMutableString *storyid;

 AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];        
 appDelegate->theNidOnDetailDisplay = storyid;
 }
```

However, when I print the string (storyid) or (theNidOnDetailDisplay) they both return null.

Am I missing something here? Should I be using instance variables?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use your AppDelegate to pass data.  Add a property to the detail view controller and assign the value to the property.

on `DetailViewController`:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableString * nid;
```

The assign it before you present:

```
DetailViewController *detail = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detail"];
detail.nid = [arrayOfNids objectAtIndex:rowNumber];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize I could do that.